# How to write unit test for ApolloClient cache update?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, apollo-client

I am trying to write a unit test to test the `update` method.

```
const [updateRecord] = useMutation(updateRecordMutation);

........


const recordHandler = (event) => {
    (async () => {
      event.preventDefault();
      try {
        await updateRecord({
        variables: { recordId: record.id, recordName: value },
        update(cache, result) {
          const updatedData = result.data?.updateRecord?.recordName;
          const cachedData: any = cache.readQuery({
            query: GetRecord,
            variables: { recordId: record.id },
          });
          if (cachedData?.Record) {
            cachedData.Record.recordName = updatedData;
            cache.writeQuery({
              query: GetRecord,
              variables: { recordId: record.id },
              data: cachedData,
            });
          }
        },
      });
      } catch (error) {
        ...
      }
    })();
  };
```

I have mocked the mutation but it doesn't update the cache. How do I write a unit test that cache has the correct values?

Comment: Did you found any solution???

Comment: @AnkitaSrivastava nope